# Smallest effective window for EWMA

Tags: moving-average

I'm using an [EWMA class](https://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/apidocs/com/codahale/metrics/EWMA.html) to calculate an exponentially weighted moving average. What I'm measuring is the rate at which bytes are arriving at my server for each client that sends a request. I want to refuse requests that are being transmitted too slowly. This is to mitigate the [Slow HTTP Post](https://blog.qualys.com/securitylabs/2011/11/02/how-to-protect-against-slow-http-attacks) attack.

I'm trying to figure out the optimal time interval for calculating the moving average. Not having expertise in statistics, I am assuming that a window too small will not give sufficient smoothing. On the other hand, I don't want a client tying up a connection for five minutes before my server decides it's sending data too slowly. I'm looking for the smallest effective window.

Any guidance on the window size would be much appreciated.